# Devise current_user after sign up redirects to my own controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i'm using devise as an authentication gem. Sign in works fine after it redirects to town#index through :

```
  namespace :user do
    root :to => "town#index"
  end
```

However, when i first sign up a user, it seems that current_user is not passed to the town controller and i get and error. Why is that happening ? Is there a way to fix ?

Comment: what's your redirection?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question, so I'll assume that you're creating `User` instances yourself.

After signing up a new user, you need to call `sign_in @user` or `current_user` will stay `nil`.

Comment: i'm actually using a devise created user model. I just use the route above (as mentioned in devise wiki), in order to redirect to town/index after login or sign up. So i'm not using any customizations on the register procedure.